# Store large DefaultFeatureCollection

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory, cpu-usage, geotools

I have to update `org.geotools.feature.DefaultFeatureCollection` at every 1 seconds till the app is running (more than an hour).
I have created `DefaultFeatureCollection lineCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection();` as a class member. Adding points to it at every 1 second `lineCollection.add(feature);`

```
public void addLines(Coordinate[] coords) {
        try {
            line = geometryFactory.createLineString(coords);
            featureBuilder.add(line);
            feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
            lineCollection.add(feature);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, the collection gets huge and heap memory increases gradually, resulting in high CPU usage and app lagging.
Is there a way to free memory once line is displayed on map ?

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged your question [memory-leaks] - is there any evidence you are leaking memory? You can use [jmap](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/troubleshooting.html#jmap) to check. If so the developers would love to hear about it with the evidence.

It seems more likely that you are just drawing 3600 lines (60*60) after an hour with out having any indexing. If your dataset was constant I'd recommend a `SpatialIndexFeatureCollection` but as yours changes I would suggest you use a GeoPackage or other database based store (if you already have one) that will manage a spatial index for your lines.